# configure vscode to include CMakeLists.txt file of multiple sub-project

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, cmake

I would like to configure correctly project's `settings.json` file to use `CMakeLists.txt` file of multiple sub-project.

###### My approach is given below

The structure of the project is as like as follows.

```cpp
vscode_build_cmake/
`-- task
    |-- add
    |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |   |-- include
    |   |   `-- foo.h
    |   `-- src
    |       |-- foo.cpp
    |       `-- main.cpp
    `-- print
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        |-- include
        |   `-- foo.h
        `-- src
            |-- foo.cpp
            `-- main.cpp
```

Here, `add` & `print` are completely isolated sub-project of the main project `task`. Each sub-project has their own build recipe which is written in their own `CMakeLists.txt` file. Usual steps to build sub-project is :

```bash
cd task/add
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. && make
```

Same steps is for `task/print`.

Right now I would like to perform this `build task` using VSCode Cmake tool. What I have found that I only need to make a `vscode_build_cmake/.vscode/settings.json` file where I can point to the directory of `CMakeLists.txt` file. I am now working with

```xml
{
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": false,
    "cmake.sourceDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/task/add"
}
```

I just press `ctrl+shift+p` and write in the command box `run build task` and press `Enter`. That one do the job for me and I can see `build, bin, lib` directories inside `task/add` directory.

But the problem, I am facing now is that if I need to build `print` sub-project I have to manually edit the `settings.json` file as like as follows

```xml
{
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": false,
    "cmake.sourceDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/task/print"
}
```

After that, I have to `delete cache and reconfigure` and `build task` which perform now the build task only for `print` project. This one is very tedious to me.

##### My desire is to know

- Is there any way to point out the both `CMakeLists.txt` file of `add` and `print` in `cmake.sourceDirectory`? Which can tell me which build task I would like to perform? Eg:

```xml
{
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": false,
    "cmake.sourceDirectory": ["${workspaceFolder}/task/add",
                              "${workspaceFolder}/task/print"]
}
```

Or ,

- Is there any way to perform build task of both sub-project.(this one is optional. Previous one is important for my case).

I am using CMake Tools v1.13.4.

Comment: If task is the main project, it should have a top CMakeLists with add_subdirectory of each subproject. AFAIK CMake Tools cannot handle multiple top CMakeLists in the same VSCode instance.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes `task` is the diectory ( i also refer to as project) where all independent sub-projects are resided. With the present structure no way to put a top CMakeLists there.

Answer (score 2):

CMake Tools supports an array of directories in [`cmake.sourceDirectory`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings) since [version 1.13.40](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#11340). See PR [#1374](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/1374).

#### Older answer

If you're intent on not having a `tasks/CMakeLists.txt` that `add_subdirectory`s `add/` and `print/`, then you can consider using VS Code's multi-root workspace feature, which the `vscode-cmake-tools` extension supports.

If you have a reason not to use / that you don't like the multi-root workspace approach, you can show your support for [vscode-cmake-tools issue #1374](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/1374) ("*Support Multiple CMakeLists.txt without Requiring a Multi-Root Workspace*") and [the proposed solutions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/1374#issuecomment-1219912289). At the time of this writing, the proposal process is still in earlier stages.